# Inconsistency in nodeset test?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML with top-level elements in this vein:

```
<chapter template="one"/>
<chapter template="two"/>
<chapter template="one"/>
<chapter template="one"/>
<chapter template="two"/>
<chapter template="one"/>
```

I'm processing these elements by looping through them with a choose statement:

```
<xsl:variable name="layout" select="@template"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($layout, 'one')">
        <xsl:call-template name="processChapterOne"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($layout, 'two')">
        <xsl:call-template name="processChaptertwo"/>
    </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise/>
</xsl:choose>
```

This works correctly. But now I'm trying to do some conditional processing, so I'm trying to find the first chapter in the list:

```
<xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::*[($layout = 'one')]) = '0'">
    <xsl:call-template name="processChapterOne"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Here's when things get weird. My test never becomes true: the value of count(...) is 4 for the first chapter in the list, and increments from there. It looks like it counts all of the top-level elements, and not just the ones named 'chapter'.
When I change the code to this:

```
<xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::*[(@template = 'one')]) = '0'">
    <xsl:call-template name="processChapterOne"/>
</xsl:when>
```

it works correctly. So I've replaced a variable with a direct reference. I can't figure out why this would make a difference. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **not working** and **working** cases are actually very different:

1. **Not working**: In `preceding-sibling::*[$layout = 'one']`,  `$layout`  is always the same value of `one` as it was when originally set in the `<xsl:variable name="layout" select="@template"/>` statement.
2. **Working**: In `preceding-sibling::*[@template = 'one']`,  `@template` varies per the `@template` attribute value of the varying preceding-sibling context nodes.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I assumed that `$layout` would expand to `@template`, but instead `$layout` is filled with the value of `@template` of the current node when I declare the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
*[(@template = 'one')]
```

Above means: count all `nodes` where attribute `template` equals the text `one`.

```
*[($layout = 'one')]
```

Above means: count all `nodes` where variable `layout` equals the text `one`. 
I think with the question you raised `$layout` is not filled with the text `one`, but it does a `xsl:call-template`. Maybe something is going wrong here?

Besides that if you don't want to count all `nodes` but only the `chapter` nodes. Do this:

```
chapter[($layout = 'one')]
chapter[(@template = 'one')]
```